# How can I add a subtitle and change the font size of ggplot plots in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I tried adding a subtitle using `+opts(subtitle="text")` but nothing showed up. The main title does work (`+opts(title="text")`).

I would also like to use a larger font for the axis (labels and coordinates), but I can't tell how to do that.

Comment: For the first question, there is a better answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724311/how-to-add-a-ggplot2-subtitle-with-different-size-and-colour

Comment: Marking a question as duplicate because there is a newer question seem very odd to me. So why was this marked as duplicate?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

`theme_get()` will show you the "hidden" options that you can use in `opts()`, post 0.91  it's `theme()`

**Current:**

```
theme(axis.text.x=element_text(size=X))
theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=X))
```

**Pre 0.91:**

```
opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(size=X))
opts(axis.text.y=theme_text(size=X))
```

Change size, to your desired size.

wrt the title, you can use "\n" to move the remaining text to a new line:

**Current:**

```
labs(title="text \n more text")
```

**Pre 0.91:**

```
opts(title="text \n more text")
```

ggplot2 doesn't have "subtitle" functionality. But you can use the \n term in any of the labels to drop down a line.

Comment: `theme_text` is now deprecated use `element_text` instead.  I would say more, but I'm searching for how to use `element_text` myself.  The help is just a stub.

Comment: Try updating your packages. The docs have been improved, and I've also updated me answer.

Answer (score 8):

Update: ggplot version 2.2.0 can do subtitles, as demonstrated e.g. in [this blog post](http://bayesball.blogspot.ca/2016/11/sub-titles-and-captions-with-ggplot2.html).

Example:

```
library(ggplot2)
packageVersion("ggplot2")  ## 2.2.0
d <- data.frame(x=1:5,y=1:5)
ggplot(d,aes(x,y))+
    labs(title="abc",subtitle="def")+
    ## default left-aligned: moved them to center alignment
    theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0.5),
          plot.subtitle=element_text(hjust=0.5))
```

[image]

Comment: Nice. It can now also do captions, which are also quite convenient to have.