# How to add a ggplot2 subtitle with different size and colour?

Tags: r, ggplot2, subtitle

I'm using ggplot2 to improve precipitation barplots.

Here's a reproducible example of what I want to achieve:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)
secu <- seq(1, 16, by=2)
melt.d <- data.frame(y=secu, x=LETTERS[1:8])
m <- ggplot(melt.d, aes(x=x, y=y)) +
  geom_bar(fill="darkblue") + 
  labs(x="Weather    stations", y="Accumulated Rainfall [mm]") +
  opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(angle=-45, hjust=0, vjust=1),
       title=expression("Rainfall"), plot.margin = unit(c(1.5, 1, 1, 1), "cm"),
       plot.title = theme_text(size = 25, face = "bold", colour = "black", vjust = 5))
z <- arrangeGrob(m, sub = textGrob("Location", x = 0, hjust = -3.5, vjust = -33, gp = gpar(fontsize = 18, col = "gray40"))) #Or guessing x and y with just option
z
```

I don't know how to avoid using guessing numbers on hjust and vjust on ggplot2? Is there a better way to put a subtitle (not just using \n, but a subtitle with different text color and size)?

I need to be able to use with ggsave to have a pdf file.

Here are two related questions:

[Add a footnote citation outside of plot area in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197738/add-a-footnote-citation-outside-of-plot-area-in-r)

[How can I add a subtitle and change the font size of ggplot plots in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3864535/how-can-i-add-a-subtitle-and-change-the-font-size-of-ggplot-plots-in-r)

Thanks for any help.

Comment: The vjust=-33 worked for me on Linux. I know that sub is meant to go below the plot, but it was the only way I got what I wanted.

Comment: for some reason this makes my plot really small and creates a huge space below the graph

Comment: @hrbrmstr s answer seems to be the way to go nowadays

Answer (score 133, accepted):

The latest ggplot2 builds (i.e., 2.1.0.9000 or newer) have subtitles and below-plot captions as built-in functionality. That means you can do this:

```
library(ggplot2) # 2.1.0.9000+ 

secu <- seq(1, 16, by=2)
melt.d <- data.frame(y=secu, x=LETTERS[1:8])

m <-  ggplot(melt.d, aes(x=x, y=y))
m <- m + geom_bar(fill="darkblue", stat="identity")
m <- m + labs(x="Weather    stations", 
              y="Accumulated Rainfall [mm]",
              title="Rainfall",
              subtitle="Location")
m <- m + theme(axis.text.x=element_text(angle=-45, hjust=0, vjust=1)) 
m <- m + theme(plot.title=element_text(size=25, hjust=0.5, face="bold", colour="maroon", vjust=-1))
m <- m + theme(plot.subtitle=element_text(size=18, hjust=0.5, face="italic", color="black"))
m
```

Comment: Error in (function (el, elname)  : 
  "plot.subtitle" is not a valid theme element name.

Comment: Please read answers: _" latest ggplot2 builds (i.e., 2.1.0.9000 or newer)"_

Answer (score 79):

**Ignore this answer** `ggplot2` version 2.2.0 has title and subtitle functionality. See @hrbrmstr's answer [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36026629/4581200).

---

You could use nested `atop` functions inside an `expression` to get different sizes.

**EDIT** Updated code for ggplot2 0.9.3

```
m <-  ggplot(melt.d, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
     geom_bar(fill="darkblue", stat = "identity") + 
     labs(x="Weather    stations", y="Accumulated Rainfall [mm]") + 
     ggtitle(expression(atop("Rainfall", atop(italic("Location"), "")))) +
     theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=-45, hjust=0, vjust=1), 
     #plot.margin = unit(c(1.5, 1, 1, 1), "cm"), 
     plot.title = element_text(size = 25, face = "bold", colour = "black", vjust = -1))
```

[image]

Comment: Hi, this is an amazing solution. I would like to use it but instead of the `atop(italic("Location")` I would like to have an object: `atop(italic(my_string_vector)`. I tried that but then the subtitle evaluated to **(my_string_vector)**. How to force this expression to use the string value and do not treat the provided text literally?

Comment: in case you are having troubles using variables you should use `bquote` instead of `expression`, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957536/add-dynamic-subtitle-using-ggplot)

Comment: @Konrad To use objects, replace `expression` with `bquote` and wrap the objects with `.()`, like this, for a main title stored in an object called "main.title" and for a subtitle stored in an object called "sub.title": 
`ggtitle(bquote(atop(.(main.title), atop(italic(.(sub.title)), ""))))` 

Credit goes to Didzis Elferts's answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957536/add-dynamic-subtitle-using-ggplot

Answer (score 12):

it's not too hard to add grobs to the gtable and make a fancy title that way,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(grid)
library(gridExtra)
library(magrittr)
library(gtable)

p <- ggplot() + 
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0.5, 1, 1, 1), "cm"))

lg <- list(textGrob("Rainfall", x=0, hjust=0, 
                    gp = gpar(fontsize=24, fontfamily="Skia", face=2, col="turquoise4")),
               textGrob("location", x=0, hjust=0, 
                        gp = gpar(fontsize=14, fontfamily="Zapfino", fontface=3, col="violetred1")),
           pointsGrob(pch=21, gp=gpar(col=NA, cex=0.5,fill="steelblue")))

margin <- unit(0.2, "line")
tg <- arrangeGrob(grobs=lg, layout_matrix=matrix(c(1,2,3,3), ncol=2),
                  widths = unit.c(grobWidth(lg[[1]]), unit(1,"null")),
                  heights = do.call(unit.c, lapply(lg[c(1,2)], grobHeight)) + margin)

grid.newpage()
ggplotGrob(p) %>%
  gtable_add_rows(sum(tg$heights), 0) %>%
  gtable_add_grob(grobs=tg, t = 1, l = 4)  %>%
  grid.draw()
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

It appears `opts` is deprecated as of ggplot 2 0.9.1 and no longer functional. This worked for me with the latest versions as of today: `+ ggtitle(expression(atop("Top line", atop(italic("2nd line"), ""))))`.

Comment: This also works without the final `, ""` - what is that part for?

Comment: Beats me. I may have copied an example I saw somewhere else.

Comment: Probably from @SandyMuspratt's answer above :P - I understand it now, `atop()` is something like a fraction without bars. So putting the second `atop()` inside the first gives you a sub-fraction, with text proportionally smaller. The `""` is the bottom of the sub-fraction. It appears to be unnecessary though - perhaps `atop()` has a default empty string for the second parameter, or something.

Comment: It appears @SandyMuspratt's answer was modified *after* I posted my answer to reflect code similar to mine. :-)

Answer (score 8):

This version uses a `gtable` function. It allows two lines of text in the title. The text, size, colour, and font face of each line can be set independently of the other. However, the function will modify a plot with a single plot panel only.

**Minor edit: Updating to ggplot2 v2.0.0**

```
# The original plot
library(ggplot2)

secu <- seq(1, 16, by = 2)
melt.d <- data.frame(y = secu, x = LETTERS[1:8])

m <- ggplot(melt.d, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
     geom_bar(fill="darkblue", stat = "identity") + 
     labs(x = "Weather    stations", y = "Accumulated Rainfall [mm]") + 
     theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = -45, hjust = 0, vjust = 1))


# The function to set text, size, colour, and face
plot.title = function(plot = NULL, text.1 = NULL, text.2 = NULL, 
   size.1 = 12,  size.2 = 12,
   col.1 = "black", col.2 = "black", 
   face.1 = "plain",  face.2 = "plain") {

library(gtable)
library(grid)

gt = ggplotGrob(plot)

text.grob1 = textGrob(text.1, y = unit(.45, "npc"), 
   gp = gpar(fontsize = size.1, col = col.1, fontface = face.1))
text.grob2 = textGrob(text.2,  y = unit(.65, "npc"), 
   gp = gpar(fontsize = size.2, col = col.2, fontface = face.2))

text = matrix(list(text.grob1, text.grob2), nrow = 2)
text = gtable_matrix(name = "title", grobs = text, 
   widths = unit(1, "null"), 
   heights = unit.c(unit(1.1, "grobheight", text.grob1) + unit(0.5, "lines"), unit(1.1,  "grobheight", text.grob2) + unit(0.5, "lines")))

gt = gtable_add_grob(gt, text, t = 2, l = 4)
gt$heights[2] = sum(text$heights)

class(gt) =  c("Title", class(gt))

gt
}

# A print method for the plot
print.Title <- function(x) {
   grid.newpage()   
   grid.draw(x)
}


# Try it out - modify the original plot
p = plot.title(m, "Rainfall", "Location", 
   size.1 = 20, size.2 = 15, 
   col.1 = "red", col.2 = "blue", 
   face.2 = "italic")

p
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You could use wrap the plot in grid.arrange and pass a custom grid-based title,

[image]

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

p <- ggplot() + 
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(0.5, 1, 1, 1), "cm"))

tg <- grobTree(textGrob("Rainfall", y=1, vjust=1, gp = gpar(fontsize=25, face=2, col="black")),
               textGrob("location", y=0, vjust=0, gp = gpar(fontsize=12, face=3, col="grey50")),
               cl="titlegrob")
heightDetails.titlegrob <- function(x) do.call(sum,lapply(x$children, grobHeight))

grid.arrange(p, top = tg)
```

Comment: Current versions of ggplot use theme and and element_text instead of opts and theme_text respectively.  Also, the ggplotGrob approach seems to fail in the current version of gridExtra (gridExtra_0.8.1) and ggplot2 (ggplot2_0.9.3.1)

Answer (score 2):

You might have noticed that Sandy's code doesn't produce a bold title for "Rainfall" - the instruction to make this bold should occur within the atop() function rather than the theme() function.

```
ggplot(melt.d, aes(x=x, y=y)) + 
 geom_bar(fill="darkblue", stat = "identity") + 
 labs(x="Weather    stations", y="Accumulated Rainfall [mm]") + 
 ggtitle(expression(atop(bold("Rainfall"), atop(italic("Location"), "")))) +
 theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle=-45, hjust=0, vjust=1),
 plot.title = element_text(size = 25, colour = "black", vjust = -1))
```

[image]