# Using an expression in plot text - Printing the value of a variable rather than its name

Tags: r, plot

I am trying to get a label to have an exponent in it. Here's the code I have

```
vall = format(cor(x,y)*cor(x,y),digits=3)
eq <- expression(paste(R^2," = ",vall,sep=""))
text(legend.x,legend.y,eq,cex=1,font=2)
```

But the text simply looks like this
[image]

How do I get the actual vall to show up (and not the text "vall")

Comment: duplicate ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973898/combining-paste-and-expression-functions-in-plot-labels

Comment: I don't think this is a duplicate but the title of this post is a bit misleading.  May I suggest reformatting the title to reflect the problem as the exponent really doesn't seem to be your problem.

Comment: `sep=""` does nothing here (appends a empty string).  This is not `base::paste` but rather `plotmath`.  Won't hurt here, but won't do what you want if a non-empty string is specified.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try `bquote()`, for example:

```
set.seed(1)
vall <- format(rnorm(1),digits=3)
eq <- bquote(bold(R^2 == .(vall)))
sq <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.1)
plot(sq, sq, type = "n")
text(0.5, 0.5, eq)
```

The reason your example doesn't work is that R never ends up evaluating `vall`:

```
> eq2 <- expression(paste(R^2," = ",vall,sep=""))
> eq2
expression(paste(R^2, " = ", vall, sep = ""))
```

plotmath tries to make something out of this but essentially `vall` is taken literally.

In general you don't need `paste()` in a plotmath expression, you can build the expression up using standard operators and through the use of layout operators. For example, for an expression equivalent to the one your example produced (unevaluated `vall`), all you really need is:

```
expression(R^2 == vall)
```

`bquote()` is one way to have an object replaced by its value in an expression. You wrap the object you want replaced by its value in `.( )`. R will then look for the object and takes its value and insert it into the expression.

See also `substitute()` for an alternative approach to this with a different interface.

Comment: @CodeGuy Re `expression(R^2 == vall)` sorry if I wasn't clear; I meant that as a way to use `expression()` to get the same behaviour as your example gave (i.e. `vall` included *literally*). It was meant to illustrate that you don't need `paste()` for such things. `bquote()` or `substitute()` is required to have `vall` replaced by its value.

Comment: What if you want to add some plaintext? I'm using an expression to simulate a subtitle in ggplot2 (see http://stackoverflow.com/a/14668651/210945), and I'd like to do something like `ggtitle(expression(atop(paste('Qg_obs vs Qg_sim for', model, 'at site', dataset), atop('colour represents angle from one point to the next', ''))`, but I can't find a way to get it to work. Have tried `.()` and bquote and substitute, but I can't figure it out.