# R boxplot title with variable name and mathematical expression

Tags: r, plot, boxplot

```
myfun <- function(x){
  plot(x = 1, y = 1, main = expression(paste(delta, "title ", x)))
}

myfun(3)
```

I'm using `paste` to pass in the `x` variable for my plot title. However, because I also have a mathematical symbol, delta, in the mix, I'm using `expression` on top of `paste`. However, this causes the variable `x` to not appear in the plot title.

## Edit:

`plot(x = 1, y = 1, main = bquote(paste(delta, "title ", .(x))))` solves the problem!

However, the same approach did not work for `boxplot(x = 1, y = 1, main = bquote(paste(delta, "title ", .(x))))`.

Comment: Try using `bquote` and wrap in `.( )` like this: `plot(x = 1, y = 1, main = bquote(paste(delta, "title ", .(x))))` ... see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14074321/3460670)...or [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4973898/combining-paste-and-expression-functions-in-plot-labels)...

Comment: Thank you. I was wondering if there's a similar solution for `boxplot` instead of `plot`? I've edited the question.

Comment: `boxplot(...)` (no main), then add `title(bquote(...))`.

Comment: try splitting up the title as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20549337/expression-and-new-line-in-plot-labels) and by @r2evans

Comment: or just `boxplot(1, 1, main = bquote(expression(paste(delta, " title ", .(x)))))`