# Add dynamic subtitle using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use ggplot to add a subtitle.  Similar question was asked here: [How to add a ggplot2 subtitle with different size and colour?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724311/how-to-add-a-ggplot2-subtitle-with-different-size-and-colour), and the answer was as follows:

```
p <- p + ggtitle(expression(atop(paste('TITLE'), atop(italic(paste('SUBTITLE')), ""))))
```

However, the words `'TITLE'` and `'SUBTITLE'` need to be hardcoded, presenting an scalability and automation problem when dealing with 1000s of plots.

This does not work:

```
plot.title = 'TITLE'
plot.subtitle = 'SUBTITLE'    
p <- p + ggtitle(expression(atop(paste(plot.title), atop(italic(paste(plot.subtitle)), ""))))
```

I guess the question on how to proper add dynamic subtitles, using this idea, boils down to: Is it possible to use character variables inside expression and atop?

Comment: Use answer of @baptiste of your linked question - just adopt it to latests ggplot2 version - it should work also with variables inside titles

Comment: @DidzisElferts 'opts' is deprecated. Use 'theme' instead.  I guess I could use opts but using deprecated stuff seems like a palliative solution.  Let's just wait, maybe some others will have other ideas...

Comment: @DidzisElferts I thought i have the latest version please calm down, don't see why you cannot let others suggest ideas...

Comment: @DidzisElferts ok but then give me sometime to try... thanks for all your help btw

Comment: Updated answer of @baptiste to previous question, now there won't be warnings about opts()

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You should use function `bquote()` instead of `expression()` to use titles that are stored as variables. And variable names should be placed inside `.()`

```
plot.title = 'TITLE'
plot.subtitle = 'SUBTITLE'

ggplot(mtcars,aes(disp,mpg))+geom_point()+
  ggtitle(bquote(atop(.(plot.title), atop(italic(.(plot.subtitle)), ""))))
```

[image]

### UPDATE - ggplot2 version 2.2.1

The latest ggplot2 version now can produce subtitles directly, so you don't have to use `bquote()` and `expression()`. The result is atchieved with argument `subtitle =` of function `labs()`.

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(disp,mpg))+geom_point()+
      labs(title = plot.title,subtitle = plot.subtitle) +
      theme(plot.subtitle = element_text(face = "italic"))
```

Comment: wow, u re the man! nice answer, nice trick! such an elegant solution, much more elegant than the long themes, opts paradigm :-)

Comment: In order to insert a third-level comment I have modified the code like that: ggplot(mtcars,aes(disp,mpg))+geom_point()+
  ggtitle(bquote(atop(.(plot.title), atop(italic(.(plot.subtitle)), "Third title without the possibility to use parameters")))). Is there another way?