# Row number showing rather than value

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am following use the answer to the question [Add dynamic subtitle using ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19957536/add-dynamic-subtitle-using-ggplot) in the following way:

```
      ggtitle(bquote(atop(.(df$fname[row]),
                          atop(italic(.(param_string)), ""))))
```

When I look at my graphs, I am seeing:

[image]

Rather than the actual value of df$fname[row], which has been verified independently to be something else.

What's going on here?

Comment: What is the value of `df$fname[row]`?

Comment: @Pascal it is "50ppm 320mW 2.txt"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
 ggtitle(bquote(atop(.(paste(df$fname[row])),atop(italic(.(param_string)), ""))))
```

Comment: Thanks that worked. Can you explain why this is the case?

Comment: many times when the column has string objects its pastes the factor number instead . for eg if a column had red blue green as values then it will print 1 for red , 2 for blue , 3 for green. U just have to try both ways and see how u get the result