# R - different font sizes when using atop

Tags: r, ggplot2

Creating a plot where the y-axis has two lines. I'm using the atop function as follows:

```
plot + ylab(expressions(atop("Line 1","Line 2")))
```

Wondering whether it would be possible to change line 1's font size i.e., make it larger than line 2?

Thanks!

Comment: Try nested `atop` functions. See responses to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11724311/how-to-add-a-ggplot2-subtitle-with-different-size-and-colour/).

Answer (score 4):

The is a mechanism to make specific sections of the fonts smaller using the plotmath `scriptstyle` function. There's also another make-even-smaller version of it. Look at the `?plotmath` page for a full list of plotmath functions.  I don't know of a plotmath strategy for making fonts larger.

```
plot + ylab(expression( atop(Line~1, 
                             scriptstyle(Line~2))
           ))
```

Note there is no `expressions` function and that I converted your text to a real R expression. You might look at the theme() settings for the element_text features for axis.title.y to increase the text size.

```
plot + ylab(expression( atop( Line~ 1,
                             scriptstyle( Line~ 2) ))) + 
       theme(axis.title.y = element_text( size = rel(2) ) )
```

Answer (score 1):

Other than `plotmath`, you could draw the text directly using `grid` functions:

```
library("gridExtra")
gt <- grobTree(ggplotGrob(plot + ylab("")), textGrob("Line 1", 0.01, 0.5, rot = 90, gp = gpar(fontsize = 18)), textGrob("Line 2", 0.025, 0.5, rot = 90, gp = gpar(fontsize = 10)))
plot.new()
grid.draw(gt)
```